# how to custom AdminURLFieldWidget to display thumbnail instead only name and browse button?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model in django application which contains ImageField.
I added in model the following code:

```
def image_tag(self):
   return u'<img src="%s" />' % self.avatar.url
image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

and updated 
list_display = ['id','image_tag']

to display thumbnail as a columns in admin form. This is works fine. But how can I do it the same in single element? Is it possible to change AdminURLFieldWidget render method? Maybe is another option see thumbnail instead name and browse button?

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution for my problem. Below the source:

http://www.psychicorigami.com/2009/06/20/django-simple-admin-imagefield-thumbnail/

Tested in Django 1.6.5